# gnome-terminal (also LibreOffice) doesn't launch any more

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have a problem with gnome-terminal; since 2 or 3 days ago, it doesn't launch any more.

It began with LibreOffice, which for no reason I know of also didn't launch anymore.

I'm actually able to use Gnome-Terminal with VisualStudio Code, which contains terminal, but when I try to launch it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or just click on it, nothing happens.

I got those following lines:

```
soyrimk@Process:~$ gnome-terminal 
# Error creating terminal: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
soyrimk@Process:~$ libreoffice
Application Error
soyrimk@Process:~$
```

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same symptom (though I doubt it was the same problem). In my case, it was due to an application I had built for my $HOME folder and for which certain libraries had been created under `$HOME/.local/lib` and perhaps `$HOME/.local/libexec` as well. Then I upgraded the OS (for me, it was going from 19.10 to 20.04) and I could no longer launch gnome-terminal.

My problem may not have been the same as yours, but if you can do an `apt depends gnome-terminal` that might give you a good starting point to look (in my case, I think it was the gir1xxx dependency). Gnome-terminal has a Python3 wrapper so it may involve something recent on your system involving Python3.

Comment: So I did the "apt depends gnome-terminal" and I got a lot of depends, and Python3 is also a part of it, I'm still looking how to deal with that

Comment: You may try doing a "sudo journalctl -xe" or "sudo less /var/log/syslog" (either one) to look at system log messages right after you try to run the gnome-terminal command. I don't think VS Code is running gnome-terminal, but just spawning a bash shell. Anyways, the above commands can give you some ideas as to what is going wrong and why.

Comment: Oh! Also, try doing a "sudo apt-get check" to make sure there are no broken packages on your system.